# Override TYPO3 standard template paths with a FluidTYPO3 driven page?

Tags: typo3, typo3-8.x

I have a TYPO3 (8.7.x) page that uses FluidTYPO3 content elements (flux 9.0.1) and a provider extension. The page is working and now I need to alter the default rendering of TYPO3 bullets CE. Therefore I try to configure additional template/partial/layout paths to override the default bullets templates:

```
lib.contentElement.templateRootPaths.90 = EXT:provider_ext/Resources/Private/Templates/
lib.contentElement.partialRootPaths.90 = EXT:provider_ext/Resources/Private/Partials/
lib.contentElement.layoutRootPaths.90 = EXT:provider_ext/Resources/Private/Layouts/
```

The bullets gets overridden successfully. But after configuring the additional paths I get an exception while rendering (existing) header CEs:

```
Wed, 22 Jan 2020 16:45:22 +0100 [ALERT] request="db4bb2a9741ea" component="TYPO3.CMS.Frontend.ContentObject.Exception.ProductionExceptionHandler":
Oops, an error occurred! Code: 2020014756452233e33932 - 
{"exception":"TYPO3Fluid\\Fluid\\View\\Exception\\InvalidSectionException: Section \"Main\" does not exist.
in \/html\/typo3\/typo3_src-8.7.30\/vendor\/typo3fluid\/fluid\/src\/View\/AbstractTemplateView.php:269
\nStack trace:\n#0 [...]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be referencing a partial's section "Main" which does not have this section. Or your layout tries to render section "Main" from the template.

You would add the section like that

```
<f:section name="Main">
  ...
</f:section>
```

Comment: I was just wondering that after adding the path a standard fluid_styled_content element no longer works. But now it is clear: this caused the wrong layout to be used.

Thanks a lot!